# magento - Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 31719424) (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

Tags: php, magento, memory

I am working with one magento site which is having more than 50,000 products. Site was working fine on the server before 5-6 days back when I saw. But suddenly it is giving an out of memory error.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 14680064) (tried to allocate 875 bytes) in /home/shirtcompany/public_html/mysite/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php on line 194
```

I have tried with setting the memory limit from index.php file as  -

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "500M");
ini_set("max_execution_time", "300");
```

but whenever I tried to load the page with changing the memory limit value, Internal Error Occurs or it gives same Out Of Memory Error with different file name alternatively.

```
Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 27787264) (tried to allocate 99 bytes) in /home/shirtcompany/public_html/digitalhill/DigitalHill/lib/Varien/Object.php on line
```

I have tried with changing the memory limit upto `10000M`  but no use. 
Also I tried with removing all the cache data from the server.

Can anybody help to get rid of this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the ini_set to be `ini_set('memory_limit', -1)`.